# Listing values from `foreach`

Tags: php

I'm trying to get values from `foreach` loop, but I have a weird issue with it.

```
<?php $all_plugins = get_plugins(); ?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Delay</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    <?php foreach ( $all_plugins as $all_plugin ) { ?>
        <form method="post">
            <tr>
                <?php
                $replaced       = str_replace( [ ':', '-', '/', '&', '_', ' ' ], '', $all_plugin['Name'] );
                $low_characters = strtolower( $replaced );
                ?>
                <td><?= $low_characters ?></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="<?= $all_plugin['Title'] ?>"></td>
                <td><input type="submit" class="button button-primary" name="<?= $low_characters ?>" value="Save"></td>
            </tr>
        </form>
        
        <?php
        if ( isset( $_POST[ $low_characters ] ) ) {
            $test = $_POST[ $all_plugin['Title'] ];

            echo $low_characters;
            echo $test;
        }
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Here is `var_dump` of the `$all_plugins`

```
array(8) {
  ["akismet/akismet.php"]=>
  array(13) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(17) "Akismet Anti-Spam"
    ["PluginURI"]=>
    string(20) "https://akismet.com/"
    ["Version"]=>
    string(5) "4.1.6"
    ["Description"]=>
    string(279) "Used by millions, Akismet is quite possibly the best way in the world to protect your blog from spam. It keeps your site protected even while you sleep. To get started: activate the Akismet plugin and then go to your Akismet Settings page to set up your API key."
    ["Author"]=>
    string(10) "Automattic"
    ["AuthorURI"]=>
    string(41) "https://automattic.com/wordpress-plugins/"
    ["TextDomain"]=>
    string(7) "akismet"
    ["DomainPath"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Network"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["RequiresWP"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["RequiresPHP"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Title"]=>
    string(17) "Akismet Anti-Spam"
    ["AuthorName"]=>
    string(10) "Automattic"
  }
  ["bbpress/bbpress.php"]=>
  array(13) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(7) "bbPress"
    ["PluginURI"]=>
    string(19) "https://bbpress.org"
    ["Version"]=>
    string(5) "2.6.5"
    ["Description"]=>
    string(70) "bbPress is forum software with a twist from the creators of WordPress."
    ["Author"]=>
    string(24) "The bbPress Contributors"
    ["AuthorURI"]=>
    string(19) "https://bbpress.org"
    ["TextDomain"]=>
    string(7) "bbpress"
    ["DomainPath"]=>
    string(11) "/languages/"
    ["Network"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["RequiresWP"]=>
    string(3) "4.7"
    ["RequiresPHP"]=>
    string(6) "5.6.20"
    ["Title"]=>
    string(7) "bbPress"
    ["AuthorName"]=>
    string(24) "The bbPress Contributors"
  }
  ["buddypress/bp-loader.php"]=>
  array(13) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(10) "BuddyPress"
    ["PluginURI"]=>
    string(23) "https://buddypress.org/"
    ["Version"]=>
    string(5) "6.1.0"
    ["Description"]=>
    string(126) "BuddyPress adds community features to WordPress. Member Profiles, Activity Streams, Direct Messaging, Notifications, and more!"
    ["Author"]=>
    string(24) "The BuddyPress Community"
    ["AuthorURI"]=>
    string(23) "https://buddypress.org/"
    ["TextDomain"]=>
    string(10) "buddypress"
    ["DomainPath"]=>
    string(14) "/bp-languages/"
    ["Network"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["RequiresWP"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["RequiresPHP"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Title"]=>
    string(10) "BuddyPress"
    ["AuthorName"]=>
    string(24) "The BuddyPress Community"
  }
  ["classic-editor/classic-editor.php"]=>
  array(13) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(14) "Classic Editor"
    ["PluginURI"]=>
    string(45) "https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/"
    ["Version"]=>
    string(3) "1.5"
    ["Description"]=>
    string(154) "Enables the WordPress classic editor and the old-style Edit Post screen with TinyMCE, Meta Boxes, etc. Supports the older plugins that extend this screen."
    ["Author"]=>
    string(22) "WordPress Contributors"
    ["AuthorURI"]=>
    string(44) "https://github.com/WordPress/classic-editor/"
    ["TextDomain"]=>
    string(14) "classic-editor"
    ["DomainPath"]=>
    string(10) "/languages"
    ["Network"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["RequiresWP"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["RequiresPHP"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Title"]=>
    string(14) "Classic Editor"
    ["AuthorName"]=>
    string(22) "WordPress Contributors"
  }
  ["gutenberg/gutenberg.php"]=>
  array(13) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(9) "Gutenberg"
    ["PluginURI"]=>
    string(38) "https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg"
    ["Version"]=>
    string(5) "8.4.0"
    ["Description"]=>
    string(85) "Printing since 1440. This is the development plugin for the new block editor in core."
    ["Author"]=>
    string(14) "Gutenberg Team"
    ["AuthorURI"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["TextDomain"]=>
    string(9) "gutenberg"
    ["DomainPath"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Network"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["RequiresWP"]=>
    string(3) "5.3"
    ["RequiresPHP"]=>
    string(3) "5.6"
    ["Title"]=>
    string(9) "Gutenberg"
    ["AuthorName"]=>
    string(14) "Gutenberg Team"
  }
  ["health-check/health-check.php"]=>
  array(13) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(30) "Health Check & Troubleshooting"
    ["PluginURI"]=>
    string(43) "https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/"
    ["Version"]=>
    string(5) "1.4.4"
    ["Description"]=>
    string(44) "Checks the health of your WordPress install."
    ["Author"]=>
    string(27) "The WordPress.org community"
    ["AuthorURI"]=>
    string(43) "https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/"
    ["TextDomain"]=>
    string(12) "health-check"
    ["DomainPath"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Network"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["RequiresWP"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["RequiresPHP"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Title"]=>
    string(30) "Health Check & Troubleshooting"
    ["AuthorName"]=>
    string(27) "The WordPress.org community"
  }
  ["hello.php"]=>
  array(13) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(11) "Hello Dolly"
    ["PluginURI"]=>
    string(41) "http://wordpress.org/plugins/hello-dolly/"
    ["Version"]=>
    string(5) "1.7.2"
    ["Description"]=>
    string(295) "This is not just a plugin, it symbolizes the hope and enthusiasm of an entire generation summed up in two words sung most famously by Louis Armstrong: Hello, Dolly. When activated you will randomly see a lyric from Hello, Dolly in the upper right of your admin screen on every page."
    ["Author"]=>
    string(14) "Matt Mullenweg"
    ["AuthorURI"]=>
    string(13) "http://ma.tt/"
    ["TextDomain"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["DomainPath"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Network"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["RequiresWP"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["RequiresPHP"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Title"]=>
    string(11) "Hello Dolly"
    ["AuthorName"]=>
    string(14) "Matt Mullenweg"
  }
  ["wp-delay-load/wp-delay-load.php"]=>
  array(13) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(13) "WP Delay Load"
    ["PluginURI"]=>
    string(25) "https://www.fixrunner.com"
    ["Version"]=>
    string(5) "1.0.0"
    ["Description"]=>
    string(89) "Great plugin to delay your plugins, scripts and assets in order to speed up your website."
    ["Author"]=>
    string(31) "FixRunner "
    ["AuthorURI"]=>
    string(25) "https://www.fixrunner.com"
    ["TextDomain"]=>
    string(13) "wp-delay-load"
    ["DomainPath"]=>
    string(10) "/languages"
    ["Network"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["RequiresWP"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["RequiresPHP"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Title"]=>
    string(13) "WP Delay Load"
    ["AuthorName"]=>
    string(31) "FixRunner "
  }
}
```

[This is the form on the front](https://prnt.sc/te5k97)

Odd thing is that when I, for example, click on `bbpress` and add second and click on Save, I get desired value, but if I add second on the `akismetantispam` and click on Save I get the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: Akismet Anti-Spam in C:\xampp\htdocs\wpdelayload\wp-content\plugins\wp-delay-load\include\Base\Functions.php on line 254
akismetantispam
```

Here is the generated `HTML` code:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Delay</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <form method="post" _lpchecked="1"></form>
    <tr>
        <td>akismetantispam</td>

        <td><input type="text" name="Akismet Anti-Spam" class=""></td>

        <td><input type="submit" class="button button-primary" name="akismetantispam" value="Save"></td>
    </tr>
    <form method="post"></form>
    <tr>
        <td>bbpress</td>

        <td><input type="text" name="bbPress"></td>

        <td><input type="submit" class="button button-primary" name="bbpress" value="Save"></td>
    </tr>
    <form method="post"></form>
    <tr>
        <td>buddypress</td>

        <td><input type="text" name="BuddyPress"></td>

        <td><input type="submit" class="button button-primary" name="buddypress" value="Save"></td>
    </tr>
    <form method="post"></form>
    <tr>
        <td>classiceditor</td>

        <td><input type="text" name="Classic Editor"></td>

        <td><input type="submit" class="button button-primary" name="classiceditor" value="Save"></td>
    </tr>
    <form method="post"></form>
    <tr>
        <td>gutenberg</td>

        <td><input type="text" name="Gutenberg"></td>

        <td><input type="submit" class="button button-primary" name="gutenberg" value="Save"></td>
    </tr>
    <form method="post"></form>
    <tr>
        <td>healthchecktroubleshooting</td>

        <td><input type="text" name="Health Check &amp; Troubleshooting"></td>

        <td><input type="submit" class="button button-primary" name="healthchecktroubleshooting" value="Save"></td>
    </tr>
    <form method="post"></form>
    <tr>
        <td>hellodolly</td>

        <td><input type="text" name="Hello Dolly"></td>

        <td><input type="submit" class="button button-primary" name="hellodolly" value="Save"></td>
    </tr>
    <form method="post"></form>
    <tr>
        <td>wpdelayload</td>

        <td><input type="text" name="WP Delay Load"></td>

        <td><input type="submit" class="button button-primary" name="wpdelayload" value="Save"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question with the HTML of the form you're submitting, not an image of it. To help you debug this further we'll need to see the input names. Also please explain why this is "odd" behavior and what you're expecting to happen. As it's written, the notice explains that the index `Akismet Anti-Spam` doesn't exist in the variable on line 254 of Functions.php (presumably `$test = $_POST[ $all_plugin['Title'] ];`. Did you mean to use `$test = $_POST[$low_characters];` instead?

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones Thanks! When I add 5 seconds on bbpress, for example, I got this [result](https://prnt.sc/te5szg). But if I do that for akismet (which is pulled from the same variable as bbpress) I have got an error. If you check dumped result you will know what is the inside name attributes.

Comment: I know you posted your PHP code, but could you post the generated HTML code too? That will help us debug any input names better or potential typos. Images are not a very efficient way to try to debug code.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones Sure. I've just updated my question with the generated `HTML` code at the very bottom.

Comment: It would have helped a lot if you'd given clear evidence at the start rather than hours after posting the question

Comment: @Martin Sorry on that. Could you edit your please edit your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Per my testing, what gets submitted with Akismet is a $_POST value with a key of `Akismet_Anti-Spam` (note the underscore).

```
array(2) {
  ["Akismet_Anti-Spam"]=> string(1) "3"
  ["akismetantispam"]=> string(4) "Save"
}
```

And you're trying to get a value with a key of `Akismet Anti-Spam`, which doesn't exist in `$_POST`. My suggestion for fixing this would be to remove the `name` from the `submit` (because you don't really need to know that if you're also submitting the text input), and then changing the name of the text input to be the lowercase version (no spaces or other punctuation).

```
<form method="post">
    <tr>
        <?php
        $replaced       = str_replace( [ ':', '-', '/', '&', '_', ' ' ], '', $all_plugin['Name'] );
        $low_characters = strtolower( $replaced );
        ?>
        <td><?= $low_characters ?></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="<?= $low_characters ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Save"></td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

Edit: if you also need the name, I'd recommend adding a hidden input to each form  like `<input type="hidden" name="plugin_name" value="Akismat Anti-Spam" />` so that will get submitted too.

```
<td>
  <input type="text" name="<?= $low_characters ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="plugin_name" value="<?= $all_plugin['Title']; ?>">
</td>
```

and `var_dump($_POST)` will show the value and plugin name (with a space) submitted:

```
array(2) {
  ["akismetantispam"]=> string(1) "5"
  ["plugin_name"]=> string(17) "Akismet Anti-Spam"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try.

Comment: But how to access it if I delete the name attribute from form? How to use `isset()` on submit?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to access? Currently inside of your foreach loop you can do `if (isset($_POST[$low_characters])) { $test = $_POST[$low_characters]; }` to get the submitted value of `5`. Or you could check `$_POST['plugin_name']` to get the value `Akismet Anti-Spam` if you wanted. Another option is to add another hidden input `<input name="plugin_lowercase" value="<?= $low_characters; ?>" />`. That would allow you to access `$_POST[$_POST['plugin_lowercase']]` (static key of `plugin_lowercase`) to get `5` instead of looping over all plugins to find this value.